# Get record from particular department which is satisfying the condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table tab1 (dep varchar2(10), val number);

begin 
  insert into tab1 values ('a',10)
  insert into tab1 values ('a',20)
  insert into tab1 values ('a',30)
  insert into tab1 values ('b',10)
  insert into tab1 values ('b',20)
  insert into tab1 values ('c',10)
end;
```

i need `DEP` and value matched only with `10,20,30`

output:

```
DEP VAL
--- ---
a   10
a   20
a   30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT dep
FROM tab1
WHERE val IN (10, 20, 30)
GROUP BY dep
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

This assumes no duplicate rows.

If you want those three *and no others*, then you can use conditional aggregation.  Here is one simple method:

```
SELECT dep
FROM tab1
GROUP BY dep
HAVING LISTAGG(val, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) = '10,20,30';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the departments with `val` having valid values 10 and 20 and 30 and no other value, then:

```
select dep
from tab1
group by dep
having 
  count(distinct val) = 3
  and
  sum(case when val not in (10, 20, 30) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3dd7d41c511c3ba069f26f75d3b8e832).

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT * FROM tab1
WHERE dep = 'Your Desired Dept Name Here'
AND val IN (10,20,30)
```

For your case, if you wants to show records from Dept = A, the query will be as follow-

```
SELECT * FROM tab1
WHERE dep = 'a'
AND val IN (10,20,30)
```

If you wants all dept name that has all three value (10,20 & 30) in it, you can use this following script-

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1
WHERE Dep IN
(
    SELECT DEP 
    FROM tab1
    WHERE val IN (10,20,30)
    GROUP BY Dep
    HAVING COUNT(Val) = COUNT(DISTINCT Val) 
)
```

Comment: mkrabbani just consider i dont know the dep name. just give the solution by using  only val column value

Comment: Then just use - WHERE val IN (10,20,30)